# Which siege weapon in ESO PVP does the most damage?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

Which siege weapon does the most damage, to players and to buildings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I experimented with the siege engines on resource towers and on the dummies on the training field, and got some numbers about them:

#### Balistas

- Balista
      
  **2000** to structures
      
  **270** to Units
- Fire Balista
      
  **1000** to Structures
      
  **1080** to Units over 3 seconds (**360** per second)
- Lightning Balista
      
  **1000** to Structures
      
  **810** to Units over 3 seconds (**270** per second) and **stun**

#### Catapults

- Scattershot Catapult
      
  **2000** to Structures
      
  **180** to Units
- Meatbag Catapult
      
  **500** to Structures
      
  **540** to Units over 3 seconds (**180** per second)
- Oil Catapult
      
  **500** to Structures
      
  **451** to Units and **ensnare**

#### Trebuchets

- Stone Trebutchet
      
  **2500** to Structures
      
  **360** to Units
- Iceball Trebutchet
      
  **500** to Structures
      
  **225** to Units and **ensnare**
- Firepot Trebutchet
      
  **2000** to Structure
      
  higher than **2400** to Units. The first dot destroys a 800 hp dummy, so I couldn't really measure it

#### Battering Rams

- Battering Ram
      
  It is difficult to measure it, because it may vary between having 3 to 6 players near a ram, and you need an actual enemy keep door to measure it, and it is a mess during battle.

#### Flaming Oil

- Flaming Oil
    
  **810** to Units over 3 seconds (**270** per second)

I didn't have the opportunity to test the siege weapons against other siege weapons in the field.

Comment: I didn't measure the damage done to other siege engines. If someone offers himself to it.

Comment: very excellent; very grateful. this will help many

Comment: The damage values to units may vary due to armor and magic resistance stats. Also, keep in mind that Trebuchets have a longer cooldown time between shots, almost the double of Balistas and Catapults. Balistas and Scattershot Catapults may have high dps rate on structures than trebs, if they are in range.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is also explained during the campaign introduction/tutorial, but basically you've got five types of siege engines/deployables:

- **Ballistas** offer the highest single target/small area damage and are most effective against single players and other siege engines.
- **Catapults** offer the highest area of effect damage as well as extra effects such as snares (also available on other siege engines, but less effective due to smaller area).
- **Trebuchets** offer the highest damage against structures such as walls, gateways, etc.
- **Rams** may only be used against keep doors for obvious reasons.
- While technically not siege engines, **forward camps** are purchased and placed just like siege engines and allow a limited number of players to use them as wayshrines when respawning.

Comment: I also learned that, apparently, catapults do not damage buildings. Am I wrong..?

Comment: Never tried it, but even if they do, their damage is significantly lower compared to trebuchets.